# Is blender more superior with the node editor then without it?

Tags: node-editor

What I mean is - Can you do things in the node editor that would not be possible if it is removed? Is the node editor only a visual representation of other approaches for the same thing?

Comment: To specify my last question more clearer - "Is the node editor only a visual representation of other approaches for the same thing?" - For example, in the node editor, Shift/A/Shader/diffuse, is the same as if you go to the material button in the properties panel and click Diffuse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Cycles materials most of the node editor's functionality can be achieved in the material tab. What is missing is the creation and editing functionality of node groups. Also, working in the node editor is much less confusing than using the visualization in the material tab.

For Blender Internal's node-materials, node textures and the compositor there is no equivalent in another part of Blender. If you removed the node editor, you could not use these features at all.